# Странное поведение функции MAX в objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Если использовать `NSUInteger` то функция `MAX` похоже сравнивает модули, что очень нелогично, в примере ниже получается что `-3 > 0`.

Проблема решается использованием `NSInteger` вместо `NSUInteger`, объясните как работает эта функция.

```
NSUInteger number = 2;
NSInteger signedResult = MAX(number - 5, 0);
NSUInteger unsignedResult = MAX(number - 5, 0);
NSLog(@"NSInteger  result = %i", signedResult);
NSLog(@"NSUInteger result = %i", unsignedResult);
```

результат

```
2014-04-17 10:23:35.717 Test[1706:90b] NSInteger  result = -3
2014-04-17 10:23:35.717 Test[1706:90b] NSUInteger result = -3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если посмотреть на реализацию макроса, то там написано:

```
#define MAX(A,B) __NSMAX_IMPL__(A,B,__COUNTER__)
#define __NSMAX_IMPL__(A,B,L) ({ __typeof__(A) __NSX_PASTE__(__a,L) = (A);...

__typeof__(A) __NSX_PASTE__(__a,L) = (A) можно раскрыть как (для Вашего примера):
NSUInteger temp_name = (2 - 5);
```

-3, если привести его к беззнаковому целому = очень большое беззнаковое целое. Вот Вам и ответ. Более того, у Вас ошибка. Если вы хотите вывести на экран беззнаковое целое, то:

```
NSLog(@"NSUInteger result = %u", unsignedResult);
```

Такая запись сразу бы указала на Вашу ошибку

Answer (score 3):

Макрос MAX возвращает тот же тип, что и тип аргументов макроса.
Оба аргумента макроса должны иметь один и тот же тип.

```
NSInteger - int для 32bit и long для 64bit
NSUInteger - unsigned int для 32bit и unsigned long для 64bit
```

Типы разные. См. условие использования макроса выше